# MY Sql group by taking too much time

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, query-performance

My sql query is taking 8 sec to run that is worst see my query below. I needed total users count month wise logged in on my server from last year

```
SELECT `updated_at`, COUNT(`id`) AS `total`  
FROM `table` 
    USE INDEX (`updated_at`) 
WHERE `updated_at` BETWEEN '2017-07-06' AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY MONTH(`updated_at`), YEAR(`updated_at`) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I also try to explain the query and see what's going wrong, also used index but nothing work for me.

I have so many queries like this which is taking too many time already spent too much time.

see the explain result below.

[image]

Comment: `GROUP BY` by an expression cannot be optimized by server (and no hints can help). Use indexed calculated fields if your server version allows it (8+). **PS.** And your `ORDER BY` makes no sence (is close to `ORDER BY RAND()`).

Comment: Please consider reading the following articles: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)_. Currently your question isn't answerable and will possibly be closed as [**too broad**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: What's the type of `updated_at`? DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP? Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` in the question.

Comment: Scanning a million rows takes 8 seconds.  Period.

Answer (score 1):

Several things you could do:

- add an index on `(updated_at)`, if there isn't one.
- remove the `USE INDEX` hint.
- remove `updated_at` from the select list and `ORDER BY id`. It makes no sense and would be rejected in recent (5.7+) versions anyway as invalid syntax.
- use `ORDER BY YEAR(updated_at), MONTH(updated_at)` instead.
- combine the `GROUP BY` with the `ORDER BY`.

The new query:

```
SELECT YEAR(updated_at) AS year,
       MONTH(updated_at) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS total  
FROM `table`       -- I hope the table has a more sensible name
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN '2017-07-06' AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at) DESC,
         MONTH(updated_at) DESC
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I used Index(updated_at) already and also run your query which you provided and it takes 7 sec to show records updated at column is timestamp this table contain "2015092" records and increasing 1000 daily

"Showing rows 0 - 12 (13 total, Query took 7.6845 sec)"